# Make website run javascript bookmarklet on page load

Tags: javascript, web, bookmarklet, tumblr, autoscroll

How do i convert this bookmarklet that "auto scrolls" so that i can put it in my website to auto run when the page loads. I tried using the code as it is, but i think i have to change some things before the website will read it.

```
   javascript:/*The%20Autoscroll%20Bookmarket:Tim%20Harper:http://tim.theenchanter.com*/var%20_ss_interval_pointer;_ss_speed=1;_ss_speed_pairs=[[0,0],[1,200.0],[1,120.0],[1,72.0],[1,43.2],[1,25.9],[2,31.0],[4,37.2],[8,44.8],[8,26.4],[16,32.0]];_ss_last_onkeypress%20=%20document.onkeypress;_ss_stop=function(){clearTimeout(_ss_interval_pointer)};_ss_start=function(){_ss_abs_speed=Math.abs(_ss_speed);_ss_direction=_ss_speed/_ss_abs_speed;_ss_speed_pair=_ss_speed_pairs[_ss_abs_speed];_ss_interval_pointer=setInterval(%27scrollBy(0,%27+_ss_direction*_ss_speed_pair[0]+%27);%20if((pageYOffset%3c=1)||(pageYOffset==document.height-innerHeight))%20_ss_speed=0;%27,_ss_speed_pair[1]);};_ss_adj=function(q){_ss_speed+=q;if(Math.abs(_ss_speed)%3e=_ss_speed_pairs.length)_ss_speed=(_ss_speed_pairs.length-1)*(_ss_speed/Math.abs(_ss_speed))};_ss_quit=function(){_ss_stop();document.onkeypress=_ss_last_onkeypress;};document.onkeypress=function(e){if((e.charCode==113)||(e.keyCode==27)){_ss_quit();return;};if(e.charCode%3e=48&&e.charCode%3c=57)_ss_speed=e.charCode-48;else%20switch(e.charCode){case%2095:_ss_adj(-2);case%2045:_ss_adj(-1);break;case%2043:_ss_adj(2);case%2061:_ss_adj(1);break;};_ss_stop();_ss_start();};_ss_stop();_ss_start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this code, at the end of your page just before `</body>` end tag. It will self-execute:

```
<script>
    (function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout(arguments.callee,100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the bookmarklet but use something else along the lines of this...

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

and

```
<body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html

Comment: where would i put each part of these codes in the tumblr html, i tried putting it in custom css, and in the head section but it still doesn't work

Comment: also you forgot to include the < on the function action at the top

Comment: The first code snippet would go between the `<head>` tags. The second part replaces the standard `<body>` tag.

Comment: but this absolutely doesn't work, theres probably more to it, i need something simple like a bookmarklet that i can just paste in to the custom css section.

Comment: It is not possible to scroll a page via pure css. The bookmarklet is also javascript and can't go in the css page. How much of the Tumblr layout do you have control over, just the CSS?

Comment: Okay, so what you would do is anywhere in the head section, paste the first snippet between `<script>` and `</script>` tags. Then, change the `<body>` tag to `<body onLoad="pageScroll()">`.

Comment: still can't get it, :( i did exactly that and it won't load at least I'm pretty sure i put them in the right place and followed all the commands

Comment: at the very top of the code right under <head> i pasted <script><function pageScroll() {
            window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
            scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
    }</script>

Comment: at the very bottom at every point i anything said body i pasted <body onLoad="pageScroll()"> and it still doesn't work

Comment: There is an extra `<` in the code you pasted. `<script><`. Also make sure you change the body to onload. If you look at the link I posted, it will show you how the code's supposed to work.

Comment: It only goes on the `<body>` tag... look at the link.

Comment: still not working pasted it here <body> 
    
    <body onload="pageScroll()">
    
 <header>

Comment: can you have a look at the girder.com/kodi.txt and tell me exactly where to paste and exactly how it should look. I looked at your link and it says the same thing you are saying, there is only one <body> tag on my html and i put it there. SO for an example say paste between <body> and <header> and paste this exactly <example code #*%@@>  so then it will work